# Unable to show ListView data in a new page in Xamarin.Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an app that runs on a RFID scanner. One feature is, after scanning multiple tags, user clicks a button and the program jumps to a new page and display all the scanned data in desired format.

I've tested my code that the data has been passed to the List where it should be. But I just failed to display them.

Code in **MainActivity.cs** that switching page and passing scanned data:

```
    private void OnClickButtonScan(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ListviewActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("AviTagList", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scannedAviTagList));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Two layouts, one is the new page, one is the listview row:

**tag_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/taglistview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="EPC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtEPC"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The new page activity:

**ListviewActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "ListviewActivity")]
public class ListviewActivity : Activity
{
    private ListView tagListView;
    private List<AviTag> scannedAviTagList = new List<AviTag>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.tag_listview);
        tagListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.taglistview);
        // Create your application here
        string aviTagListJson = Intent.GetStringExtra("AviTagList");
        this.scannedAviTagList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AviTag>>(aviTagListJson);

        TagListviewAdapter tagReadListAdapter = new TagListviewAdapter(this, this.scannedAviTagList);
        tagListView.Adapter = tagReadListAdapter;
    }
}
```

The data adapter to the view:

**TagListviewAdapter.cs**

```
public class TagListviewAdapter : BaseAdapter<AviTag>
{
    public List<AviTag> TagList { get; set; }
    private Context context;

    public TagListviewAdapter(Context context, List<AviTag> items)
    {
        this.TagList = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;
        TagListviewAdapterViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as TagListviewAdapterViewHolder;

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new TagListviewAdapterViewHolder();
            var inflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, parent, false);
            holder.EPC = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEPC);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        var tagReadData = TagList[position];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagReadData.EPC))
        {
            holder.EPC.Text = tagReadData.EPC;
            holder.EPC.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            holder.EPC.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        return view;
    }

    //Fill in cound here, currently 0
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public override AviTag this[int position]
    {
        get { return TagList[position]; }
    }
}

internal class TagListviewAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    //Your adapter views to re-use
    public TextView EPC { get; set; }
}
```

Then the data class:

```
public class AviTag
{
    public string EPC { get; set; }
}
```

There is no compile error or runtime error, but I just fail to display the data. Could someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you switch to using RecyclerView instead of using ListView.

One glaring issue you have in your Adapter is that `Count` always returns 0. Instead you should change it to:

```
public override int Count => TagList?.Count ?? 0;
```

If you always return 0, the Adapter won't ever try to create rows.

Comment: It works! Stupid me, I forgot the change the default code. Thank you!

Comment: It happens to all of us :)